# Does the Potion of Treasure Finding function on all mobs in Deepholm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft there is a [Treasure Finding](http://www.wowhead.com/item=58488/potion-of-treasure-finding) potion, which "Allows you to sometimes find extra treasure from monsters in Mount Hyjal, Vashj'ir, Deepholm, Twilight Highlands and Uldum.  Lasts 1 hour.  Effect persists through death. (1 Min Cooldown)".

In [Deepholm](http://static.icy-veins.com/images/wow/lunar-festival-map-deepholm.jpg) there is a section above the Twilight Preciple where monsters will spawn over and over, and give XP and loot.

[Specifically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDylABDjRbo) this place.

**Will the potion of treasure finding work on these mobs under the current version of WoW, and all other mobs in Deepholm?**

Comment: The video you linked clearly states that they are using potion of Treasure Finding to farm these mobs. Is there a question here that I am not seeing or did you answer your own question?

Comment: @Chippies The video was released about 6 years ago, and 3 new expansions have been released for WoW since, which has heavily changed how leveling, and even professions work. I am solely using the video for a location reference, and wondering if the potions works under the current patch/version.

Comment: Why would it change?  The item is still in the game and the last major patch (7.3.5) was the one that changed leveling; profession leveling changes aren't arriving until Battle for Azeroth.  It works in any Cataclysm zones including dungeons.

Comment: @Powerlord They nerfed how many mobs spawned in that spot, and when I asked in trade chat I was met with mixed answers. I guess I can just try, but each potion is 900g.

Comment: Are you sure it's even worth spending 900g on that potion? The items you (may) get from it will be a lot cheaper if you buy them off the auction house directly. Also the materials for making it are not worth 900g either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to test the potion for myself, and while it does work I feel like that it has a greatly reduced drop rate in this area. Testing else where I would get 1 loot every 5 enemies slain, but in this specific location it was 20-25.

But yes, the potion will work, but not frequently.